# How to concatenate two dataframes in particular format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe.

```
Item       Photo1     Photo2    Photo3    Photo4   Description1  Description2  Description 3

A           A1.jpg      A2.jpg                        Nice           Beautiful
B           B1.jpg      B2.jpg    B3.jpg    B4.jpg    Ugly           Damaged
C           C1.jpg                                    Cute           Handsome     Nice
```

I separated these dataframes into:

df1(based on photo)

```
 I             A
PH           A1.jpg
PH           A2.jpg
 I             B
PH           B1.jpg
PH           B2.jpg
PH           B3.jpg
PH           B4.jpg
 I             C
PH           C1.jpg
```

df2(based on description)

```
Description Nice
Description Beautiful
Description Ugly
Description Damaged
Description Cute
Description Handsome
Description Nice
```

I tried concatenating two dataframes using:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Output:

```
 I             A
PH           A1.jpg
PH           A2.jpg
 I             B
PH           B1.jpg
PH           B2.jpg
PH           B3.jpg
PH           B4.jpg
 I             C
PH           C1.jpg
Description Nice
Description Beauiful
Description Ugly
Description Damaged
Description Cute
Description Handsome
Description Nice
```

How to concatenate in the particular format according to the first dataframe and display in the format of?

Expected Output:

```
I             A
PH           A1.jpg
PH           A2.jpg
Description Nice
Description Beauiful
I             B
PH           B1.jpg
PH           B2.jpg
PH           B3.jpg
PH           B4.jpg
Description Ugly
Description Damaged
I             C
PH           C1.jpg
Description Cute
Description Handsome
Description Nice
```

Comment: doesn't think so

Comment: df2 leaves no information on how was it split and combined.  You have to make it the same way as df1 with the `I` column in order to allow joining back.

Comment: df2 contains only the description values.

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'Photo1': ['A1.jpg', 'B1.jpg', 'C1.jpg'],
                   'Photo2': ['A2.jpg', 'B2.jpg', ''],
                   'Photo3': ['', 'B3.jpg', ''],
                   'Photo4': ['', 'B4.jpg', ''],
                   'Description1': ['Nice', 'Ugly', 'Cute'],
                   'Description2': ['Beautiful', 'Damaged', 'Handsome'],
                   'Description3': ['', '', 'Nice']})

tmp = df.T
tmp.index = ['I', 'PH', 'PH', 'PH', 'PH', 'Description', 'Description', 'Description']

df_a = tmp.loc[tmp[0]!= '', [0]].rename(columns={0: 'output'})
df_b = tmp.loc[tmp[1]!= '', [1]].rename(columns={1: 'output'})
df_c = tmp.loc[tmp[2]!= '', [2]].rename(columns={2: 'output'})

result = pd.concat([df_a, df_b, df_c])
```

result is

```
>>> result

                output
I                    A
PH              A1.jpg
PH              A2.jpg
Description       Nice
Description  Beautiful
I                    B
PH              B1.jpg
PH              B2.jpg
PH              B3.jpg
PH              B4.jpg
Description       Ugly
Description    Damaged
I                    C
PH              C1.jpg
Description       Cute
Description   Handsome
Description       Nice
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

Given df,

```
d = {'Item': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'Photo1': {0: 'A1.jpg', 1: 'B1.jpg', 2: 'C1.jpg'}, 'Photo2': {0: 'A2.jpg', 1: 'B2.jpg', 2: nan}, 'Photo3': {0: nan, 1: 'B3.jpg', 2: nan}, 'Photo4': {0: nan, 1: 'B4.jpg', 2: nan}, 'Description1': {0: 'Nice', 1: 'Ugly', 2: 'Cute'}, 'Description2': {0: 'Beautiful', 1: 'Damaged', 2: 'Handsome'}, 'Description 3': {0: None, 1: None, 2: 'Nice'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

Input Dataframe:

```
  Item  Photo1  Photo2  Photo3  Photo4 Description1 Description2 Description 3
0    A  A1.jpg  A2.jpg     NaN     NaN         Nice    Beautiful          None
1    B  B1.jpg  B2.jpg  B3.jpg  B4.jpg         Ugly      Damaged          None
2    C  C1.jpg     NaN     NaN     NaN         Cute     Handsome          Nice
```

Then df1, created:

```
 df1 = df.iloc[:, 0:5].stack()
```

Output:

```
0  Item           A
   Photo1    A1.jpg
   Photo2    A2.jpg
1  Item           B
   Photo1    B1.jpg
   Photo2    B2.jpg
   Photo3    B3.jpg
   Photo4    B4.jpg
2  Item           C
   Photo1    C1.jpg
dtype: object
```

and df2 craeated,

```
df2 = df.iloc[:,5:].stack()
```

Output:

```
0  Description1          Nice
   Description2     Beautiful
1  Description1          Ugly
   Description2       Damaged
2  Description1          Cute
   Description2      Handsome
   Description 3         Nice
dtype: object
```

Now, let's `pd.concat`, df1 and df2, using the structure of df's index and column headers to order rows:

```
pd.concat([df2, df1]).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.columns]))
```

Output:

```
0  Item                     A
   Photo1              A1.jpg
   Photo2              A2.jpg
   Photo3                 NaN
   Photo4                 NaN
   Description1          Nice
   Description2     Beautiful
   Description 3          NaN
1  Item                     B
   Photo1              B1.jpg
   Photo2              B2.jpg
   Photo3              B3.jpg
   Photo4              B4.jpg
   Description1          Ugly
   Description2       Damaged
   Description 3          NaN
2  Item                     C
   Photo1              C1.jpg
   Photo2                 NaN
   Photo3                 NaN
   Photo4                 NaN
   Description1          Cute
   Description2      Handsome
   Description 3         Nice
dtype: object
```

---

Let's try df.stack():

```
d = {'Item': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'Photo1': {0: 'A1.jpg', 1: 'B1.jpg', 2: 'C1.jpg'}, 'Photo2': {0: 'A2.jpg', 1: 'B2.jpg', 2: nan}, 'Photo3': {0: nan, 1: 'B3.jpg', 2: nan}, 'Photo4': {0: nan, 1: 'B4.jpg', 2: nan}, 'Description1': {0: 'Nice', 1: 'Ugly', 2: 'Cute'}, 'Description2': {0: 'Beautiful', 1: 'Damaged', 2: 'Handsome'}, 'Description 3': {0: None, 1: None, 2: 'Nice'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

Input Dataframe:

```
  Item  Photo1  Photo2  Photo3  Photo4 Description1 Description2 Description 3
0    A  A1.jpg  A2.jpg     NaN     NaN         Nice    Beautiful          None
1    B  B1.jpg  B2.jpg  B3.jpg  B4.jpg         Ugly      Damaged          None
2    C  C1.jpg     NaN     NaN     NaN         Cute     Handsome          Nice
```

Let's `stack`:

```
df_out = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
Item                     A
Photo1              A1.jpg
Photo2              A2.jpg
Description1          Nice
Description2     Beautiful
Item                     B
Photo1              B1.jpg
Photo2              B2.jpg
Photo3              B3.jpg
Photo4              B4.jpg
Description1          Ugly
Description2       Damaged
Item                     C
Photo1              C1.jpg
Description1          Cute
Description2      Handsome
Description 3         Nice
dtype: object
```

Comment: I don't want them like this, I want to concatenate

Comment: @AtomStore See update... Using df structure to order pd.concat results.